# Установить cookie на несколько минут на javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Устанавливаю cookie так:

```
$.cookie("name-cookie", "no", { expires: 30, path: '/'});
```

Но кукисы устанавливаются на 30 дней, а нужно на 30 минут

Я так понимаю что expires: значение в днях.

Подскажите пожалуйста как установить куки минутах?, в php я знаю как установить, а как в jquery или можно на чистом javascript

Answer (score 2):

Всё разобрался сам:

```
var new_minut = new Date();
new_minut.setMinutes( 30 + new_minut.getMinutes());
$.cookie("name-cookie", "no", { expires: new_minut, path: '/' });
```

**Вопрос закрыт.**

Comment: чтобы закрыть вопрос и отметить вопрос решением, отметьте его зеленой галочкой (слева от ответа, под цифрой)